# Camel JPA component route is not executing fully

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql, camel-jpa

I have created a simple route using JPA component

```
    `fromF("jpa:%s?consumer.namedQuery=step1&delay=5s&consumeDelete=false&consumeLockEntity=false", Event.class.getName())
    .log("Query Fired")
    .process(exchange -> System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody()))
    .end();
```

in console I can see the query being fired

```
Hibernate: select event0_.eventId as eventId1_3_, event0_.event_desc as event_desc2_3_, event0_.event_name as event_name3_3_, event0_.event_type as event_type4_3_, event0_.valid_from_date as valid_from_date5_3_, event0_.insight as insight6_3_, event0_.is_processed as is_processed7_3_, event0_.severity as severity8_3_, event0_.source_system_name as source_system_name9_3_, event0_.valid_to_date as valid_to_date10_3_ from OV90PLFM.event event0_ where event0_.is_processed=0
```

but after this I cannot see log getting printed and the processor is also not getting executed.
after a delay a query continues to get fire but no exception is there and route processing is not completed. the log is not printing and the processor is also not getting called.
I have changed the log level still exception is not there.

I just want my route to complete its execution so i can write some thing in processor.

same query gives all the rows in database.

Please suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: I think this is the Problem with the camel version. I am using 2.20.3 and in that ProducerTeplates's send body is also not working, while it is working in 2.13.0